# how to catch exception in cppunit

Tags: c++, oop, cppunit

We use CPPUnit to test our Test framework

The tests are organized in Test fixtures (inherited from CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture)

There is a new requirement - To flush out the application buffer at the end of a test ONLY if it has failed.

I can do this in the overloaded teardown() function in the Test Fixture. 
But how to know if a test has failed.

The result of a test is checked using CPPUNIT_ASSERT.

There are around 12 test fixtures with each fixture having around 10 tests.
How to achieve this with minimal code change?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a bit on how you call your tests but my first idea would be to use a TestListener and react to the TestListener::addFailure call.

Note however that the tearDown can in theory also throw an exception (possibly through a CPPUNIT_ASSERT) which would also call the TestListener::addFailure.

If that does not work an obvious but really ugly solution is to set a flag at the end of each test method that signals that test finished successfully and call your code when the flag is not set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not clear to me how to integrate TestListener into the tests. I tried inheriting the test fixture class from TestListener. But the

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not clear to me how to integrate TestListener into the tests. I tried inheriting the test class from TestListener:            class XyzTest : public CppUnit::TestFixture, public CppUnit::TestListener. And implemented startTest(), endTest() and addFailure() inside XyzTest. But the functions are not getting invoked. The tests are invoked from class TestCaller

Comment: Can you add some code that shows how you are calling your tests?